# jsPDF rotate an image around its own center

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I am using jsPDF to create a PDF from existing objects in my canvas. Thus I have the coordinates and the rotation angle of my objects, I want to then add to my PDF. However, every image doesn't rotate around its own center, thus it changes the coordinates drastically.

```
var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a3');
doc.addImage(image, 'PNG', 100, 100, 52.916667, 52.916667, null, null, 45);
doc.save('a3.pdf');
```

Can somebody help me rotate the image around its own center?

Here is a jsFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/bx0ucszo/6/

Comment: Can you add an example where you can reproduce this?

Comment: @karthick Edited!

Comment: It appears that jsPDF doesn't support this use case directly. You could first draw the image to a canvas where you have control over the point of rotation, then convert the canvas to a datauri before finally adding the image to the PDF. It's a roundabout solution, but it should work.

Comment: why not just export the canvas itself? canvas => image and then image => jspdf.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same Issue, You can solve it by playing with the degrees in X and Y for the position.

Meaning that if when you rotate your img 45 degrees it descends some pixels on Y, my solution was to put a negative value for Y, for example -100 instead of 100

Hope it's usefull for you